# My code is giving a wrong answer on the PRIME1 question on spoj; how do I fix it?

Tags: java, primes

I am decently new to java and an absolute beginner at competitive coding. I was told to try solving problems at spoj to get the feel of it, and PRIME1 was the first one I decided to try. After learning about the eratosthenes sieve, and trying to make a working program, I got my expected results on eclipse and idone it accepted it too, but spoj said it is giving a wrong answer

The problem statement:
https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Since I was a beginner, I went through many different errors and fixed them as per advice off of the various forums I came across, from splitting on readLine to try and catching. I do not fully grasp all of these solutions and do not know if they are causing the wrong answer error. I have tried running it multiple times on eclipse and verifying the results from a prime number list and even idone it ran my code and said it was successful, though I do not know how correct it is, on account of me using the website for the first time thanks to spoj.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


class Eratosthenes {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            while(n-->0) {
                String[] inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");

                                //finding the limits

                int o=Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
                int p=Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);


                int b=(int)Math.sqrt(p);

                int[] prime=new int[p+1];

                                //assigning all values prime at first


                for(int i=0;i<=p;i++) {
                    prime [i]=1;
                }

                                //removing 0 and 1
                prime[0]=0;
                prime[1]=0;

                                //using the sieve to remove all composite multiples of primes

                for(int i=2;i<=b;i++) {
                    if(prime[i]==1) {
                        for(int j=i*2;j<=p;j+=i) {
                            prime[j]=0;
                        }
                    }
                }


                                //printing the primes
                for(int i=0;i<prime.length;i++) {
                    if(prime[i]==1) {
                        if(i>=o)
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Throwable trh) { return; }


    }
}
```

What is going wrong here? Is it actually giving incorrect outputs? Or is it something else?

Comment: You need a tutorial on debugging programs.

Comment: that I probably do... where should I go?

Comment: [Here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a good article about debugging small programs

Comment: Speak to your teacher.

Comment: Umm... I am doing this by myself... I don't have a teacher... I am yet to join college

Answer (score 0):

In competitive programming the output has to be precise.
For the sample test case, consider the difference between your output:

```
2
3
5
7
3
5
```

and the expected output:

```
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

Comment: okay so I tried it, but it doesn't seem to be accepting it even now... anything else I'm missing?

Comment: If your solution is adding ```System.out.println();``` at the end of the outer loop than that could be the issue, since in the last iteration you'd print a new line.

Comment: if I try removing the try and catch block, then spoj gives me a non-zero exit error... however the previous comment is a valid point, I'll fix that right now

Comment: I have been trying over the last hour to remove the last printed line, but to no avail, could you please help me one more time?
You can check my code [here](https://ideone.com/TC3PsU#stdin)

Comment: Yeah, apparently there is a memory constraint of 1536MB, and when you allocate an integer array of size 10^9 (which could happen) you exceed it and an exception is thrown. Sorry, it sucks that your first experience with competitive coding turned out so annoying, specially since your logic was correct. I guess they wanted you to check for every number individually if it's prime, even tough it's easier, not sure...

Comment: I clearly have a lot more to learn, I'm still in 12th actually... I thought I could start this on my own with the knowledge I have, but clearly I have a lot more to study and understand... Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Also, spoj is saying the memory allocation on my program is 4468mb... You can check my plethora of rejected submissions [here](https://www.spoj.com/status/PRIME1,amuzak/)

Comment: To remove the last printed newline try putting the newline at the start of every output block except the first.

Comment: oh wow that's genius and obvious at the same time... I'm stupid... thanks so much!!!